# Is Pokemon Bank in any way accessible?

Tags: pokemon-lets-go

Is there any possible way to access Pokemon Bank from the Switch Pokemon Let's Go games?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of writing, Pokemon Bank is not accessible on the Nintendo Switch Pokemon Let's Go games.

Currently, the only way to bring Pokemon into the game from outside is through the [Pokemon Go Park Complex](https://pokemonletsgo.pokemon.com/en-us/pokemon-go/) or by entering a redemption code.